# Validates resource references inside Android XML files

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I just created an app without any activity inside and when I add the layout and java class, I started to edit the **AndroidManifest.xml** to make the intent-filter and add the label and activity stuff. But then it shows me this:
[image: Error]

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.arvisapps.practiceapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/label">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Here's the MainActivity.java :

```
    package com.arvisapps.practiceapp;


public class MainActivity {
}
```

And my activity_main.xml(I don't think it's needed but anyway):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` needs to extend `Activity`

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {
}`

Answer (score 9):

go to File and select Invalidate Caches / Restart

[image: Menue]

Answer (score 2):

In order to validate a class as activity Your **MainActivity.java** class must extend to the `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
}
```